# Parsing mixed result from google feed api

Tags: jquery, xml, json, rss

Can someone give me example how to parse mixed feed result from google api (eg. XML + json). I'm trying to get enclosure element of the feed, but it seems that json result doesn't return it! Thanks!

Comment: worked for me as well. Accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get feeds in mixed mode you have to set results mode to MIXED_FORMAT.
all entries should now include a xmlNode from which the enclosure element can be retrieved, and the url extracted:

```
var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(feedUrl);
feed.setResultFormat(google.feeds.Feed.MIXED_FORMAT);
feed.load( function(result) {
   var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
   var entryImageUrl = entry.xmlNode.getElementsByTagName("enclosure")[0].getAttribute("url");
});
```